# Wordpress sort posts by sum of two post meta

Tags: wordpress

I know how I can sort posts by 1 post meta

```
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
$query->set('meta_key', 'thumb_ups');
$query->set('order', 'DESC');
```

But how I can sort by the sum of 2 post meta?

e.g. I want to sort by the sum of thumb_ups and thumbs_downs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` you can only do something like this:

```php
$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation'     => 'AND',
        'thumb_ups'    => [
            'key'     => 'thumb_ups',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ],
        'thumbs_downs' => [
            'key'     => 'thumbs_downs',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ],
    ],
    'orderby'    => [
        'thumb_ups'    => 'DESC',
        'thumbs_downs' => 'ASC',
    ],
];
```

But you can't do a calculation on the thumb_ups and thumbs_downs together as one field. If you want to do something like that, you'll either need to execute your own sql query or hook into a filter `(new WP_Query())->get_posts()`

---

You can try a fragile hack like this:

```php
$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation'     => 'AND',
        'thumb_ups'    => [
            'key'     => 'thumb_ups',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ],
        'thumbs_downs' => [
            'key'     => 'thumbs_downs',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ],
    ],
    'suppress_filters' => FALSE,
];
```

```php
add_filter('posts_orderby', function ($orderby, $wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    return "({$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value + mt1.meta_value) DESC, $orderby";
}, 10, 2);
```

You'll need to "un"suppress_filters and unset the `posts_orderby` filter after you're done. And this is assuming there are no other conditions in your `meta_query` field.

Although I would consider this hack fragile and I think you're better off just writing your own SQL query with `$wpdb->get_results()` at that point.